# Highlight pandas dataframe cells contained in a list

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I want to highlight dataframe cells contained in a specific list, to get better performance, I want this only happens to specific column.

1. I understand we should set `df.style` `background-color: yellow` attribute
   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html
2. we should use `df.apply` rather than `df.applymap`, later one is element-wise
   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply

Sample code is cleaned up as follows, but does not generate highlighted items at all.
Can anyone help me with this, thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import webbrowser

def write_data_to_file(filename, content):

    file = open(filename, mode='w')
    file.write(content)
    file.close()


def highlight_hot_color(col):

    hot_color = ['red', 'yellow', 'orange']
    check = [item in hot_color for item in col]
    return ['background-color: yellow' if v else '' for v in check]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.DataFrame([['Allen', 'red', 20], ['Tom', 'yellow', 30], ['Jack', 'blue', 40], ['Bob', 'grey', 50]], 
        columns=['name', 'color', 'age'])
    df.style.apply(highlight_hot_color, subset=['color'])

    html = df.to_html(index=False)
    file_name = 'test.html'
    path_name = os.path.abspath(file_name)
    url = 'file://' + path_name
    write_data_to_file(path_name, html)
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved after many hours investigation, hope this can help others.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['Allen', 'red', 20], ['Tom', 'yellow', 30], ['Jack', 'blue', 40], ['Bob', 'grey', 50]],
columns=['name', 'color', 'age'])
df_result = df.style.apply(highlight_hot_color, subset=['color'])

with open('test.html','w') as f:
f.write(df_result.render())
```